# sqlalchemy: Can't drop database on teardown

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I am trying sqlalchemy with pytest, and having the following issues

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def my_session(my_db, request):
    from my.models import Session, Base

    Base.metadata.bind = my_db
    Base.metadata.create_all()

    def teardown():
        Base.metadata.drop_all()
        Base.metadata.create_all()
    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    Session.configure(bind=my_db)

    return Session()
```

But for some reason, the data which was stored to database during previous tests is still there. And I was kind of expecting it to vanish after .drop_all() call :(

Comment: I would just enable general database log to see what queries are being executed. E.g.

1. remove all tables manually via DROP DATABASE ...; CREATE DATABASE;

2. enable general log. This is DB-specific, in MySQL:

show global variables like '%general%';
set global general_log = ON; 

3. tail the log file, then execute the tests to see what's going on.

Comment: My BE is sqlite. But in general, the debug log shows that tables are being created (e.g. I see a lot of create table messages)... And regarding drop tables... dont have any, just something like: `INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info('table_name')`. Also when I have tried to comment the create_all part, it failed as if tables was deleted... so the question in the case is how does it get the prev state :(

Comment: Close your session before drop database.

Comment: Is `my_db` a fixture or an indirect parameter passed to my_session fixture?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem with SqlAlchemy 1.4.

I could make it work using the **SqlAlchemy-Utils** package as `Base.metadata.drop_all()` was really not helping.

Instead, I used the function [`drop_database()`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database_helpers.html#drop-database), then [`create_database()`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database_helpers.html#create-database) to rebuild it.

Beware that `drop_database` will really destroy it, not only delete the metadata. The entire database will be gone and you will not even able to connect to it.

**Make sure you're really using a testing environment before trying the code below!**

Also note that  for this same reason, it can be fairly slower, especially if you're calling the tear down after every single test.

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import create_database, drop_database
from my.models import Session, Base

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def my_session(my_db, request):
    url = my_db.url
    Base.metadata.bind = my_db
    Base.metadata.create_all()

    def teardown():
        # Dropping...
        drop_database(url)
        
        # Recreating...
        create_databse(url)
        Base.metadata.create_all()
    
    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    Session.configure(bind=my_db)

    return Session()
```